# Java PreparedStatement autogenerated keys SQLException

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, sqlexception

I am trying to get the autogenerated key from my SQL Insert preparedstatement from an oracle database. I have tried mimicking every example I could find and I always get a SQLException from the .executeUpdate() call. I am certain this works fine without the second argument in the prepareStatement() call so it is not the SQL itself. Please what am I doing wrong?

I am getting the error:

```
I seem to be getting this: [1/19/15 0:50:50:462 EST] 00000054 
ConnectionEve A J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal 
connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource[extracted]. The 
exception which was received is 
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Protocol 
violation:java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
```

the code goes like this

```
    Connection conSOX = AggIOTraceUtil.getJNDISOXConnection(JNDIConn);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String sii_agg_id = null;

            if (conSOX != null)
            {                       
                preparedStatement = conSOX.prepareStatement(SII_SOX_APP_QUERY, new String[] { "SII_TASK_AGG_STATUS_ID" });
                preparedStatement.setObject(1, traceObject.getTaskName());
                preparedStatement.setObject(2, traceObject.getTaskType());
                preparedStatement.setObject(3, traceObject.getSpTaskStartedDate());
```

ETC ETC ...

```
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();                  

                    // Get the auto generated aggregation ID
                    ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
                    if (null != generatedKeys && generatedKeys.next()) {
                        log.error("Hello");
                        sii_agg_id = generatedKeys.getString(1);

                        log.error("SII AGG ID  = " + sii_agg_id);
```

My SQL query is:

```
private static final String SII_SOX_APP_QUERY = "insert into 
SII_TASK_AGG_STATUS(SII_TASK_AGG_STATUS_ID, DATA_AGG_TASK_NAME, 
"+ "TASK_TYPE, TASK_STARTED_DATE, TASK_COMPLETED_DATE, TASK_LAUNCHED_DATE,
APP_SCANNED, "+ "EXTRA_ENTITLEMENT_CHANGES, IDENTITIES_UPDATED, 
LINKS_OR_GROUPS_DELETED, GROUPS_UPDATED, "  + "IDENTITIES_CREATED, 
GROUPS_CREATED, TASK_MESSAGE, COLUMN_NAMES, DELIMITER, LINE_SKIPPED, 
"+ "LOGICAL_APP_NAME, IS_PRIMARY_TIER, AGG_STATUS, DATA_AGG_AUDIT_ID, 
SII_TASK_STATUS_ID" + ")
values(SII_TASK_AGG_STATUS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I seem to be getting this: 
[1/19/15 0:50:50:462 EST] 00000054 ConnectionEve A   J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource[extracted].  The exception which was received is com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Protocol violation:java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation

Comment: Run it again - your connection pool timed out.

Comment: You'll want to add that to your question (particularly since you can format that sort of content if you edit your question rather than trying to read it in a comment).

Comment: This has occurred multiple times. Rerunning does not seem to help.

Comment: And as I mentioned, removing the second argument from the prepareStatement() as well as the getGeneratedKeys(), the insert works fine. Its something related to getting the auto generated primary key.